# Im trying to run an app but im getting an error which says "could not find translocated node" in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

[default] LSPrefs: could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x600003002ae0> { isDir = ?, path = '/private/var/folders/k7/zdtfstr13gxcrwg98wc0k1dm0000gn/X/14ADFEAC-68C8-59CF-AC5B-21F464164A42/d/Wrapper/Dicee-iOS13.app' }, proceeding on the assumption it is not translocated: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am getting similar messages in the console when running an iOS app from XCode on the target myMac (Designed for iPad).
However, as far as I am concerned, this is just a warning that does not prevent the app from running.

More information on translocation here: https://eclecticlight.co/2021/04/19/ios-apps-are-translocated-when-run-in-macos/

Comment: I noticed this, after recently switching to Xcode on an M1, and have not found any functional problems. Hopefully it is just a warning. I created some new projects in Xcode 13, and they don't have this error, but I haven't isolated why my old (circa iOS10) projects show this. If I find something conclusive I'll add a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar error on the target My Mac (Designed for iPad).
M1 Mac, Xcode 14.0.1, MacOS Monterrey 12.6.

The app builds fine on all other targets.  It started crashing on the Mac target when I added MKLookAroundViewController to the storyboard, as shown at 36:00 in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10035/

To solve this, I deleted the Look Around view controller from the storyboard and added it programmatically instead.